# Variance of residual when error variance is known

Tags: regression

Suppose the true model is $y = 2x + \text{error}$, where $\text{error}$ is normally distributed with variance 1 and mean 0. See the R code below. Variance for any residual from the fitted model (under OLS) is given by $\text{Var}(\text{error}) \times (1 - \text{hatvalue})$. Ex: var(residual) for the first observation is 0.99.

Question: How can I verify that var(for residual for the first observation) is indeed equal to 0.99 using the data? Do I have to do sampling a good number of times but with different y values which is due to uncertainity in error and then fit a model, next compute var(of all the residuals obtained at observation 1 using all samples) and then check if it is atleast close to 0.99? Appreciate if anyone can please clarify.

```
 x <- rchisq(300,1)
 error <- rnorm(300,0,1)
 #true model
 y <- 2*x + error
 mod <- lm(y~x)
 h <- hatvalues(mod)
 #var_ei = var(epsilon) * (1-h(i))
 #for example - for the first residual i = 1
 #since variance(epsilon) = 1
 var_e1 = 1 * (1 - h[[1]])
 #var_e1 = 0.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the 0.99 is just based on that particular sample that you used to fit the model. But in reality, you know that the residuals are coming from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, since you are generating them by `rnorm(300,0,1)`. So we should expect that the $var(e_1)\sim 1$ as we increase the number of sampling. You basically need to generate the first residual i.e. $e_1$ many times and then find its variance something like the following function. See how the variance converges to one as I increase the N.

```
> var.e1=function(N){
+ e1=c(0)
+ for (i in 1:N){
+ x <- rchisq(300,1)
+  error <- rnorm(300,0,1)
+ y <- 2*x + error
+  mod <- lm(y~x)
+ e1[i]=residuals(mod)[1]}
+ return(var(e1))
+ }
> 
> var.e1(10)
[1] 0.5746906
> var.e1(100)
[1] 1.041797
> var.e1(1000)
[1] 1.010416
> var.e1(20000)
[1] 0.999911
```